# Weak Learners of Gradient Boosting Tree for Classification/ Multiclass Classification

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I am a beginner in machine learning field and I want to learn how to do multiclass classification with Gradient Boosting Tree (GBT). I have read some of the articles about GBT but for regression problem and I couldn't find the right explanation about GBT for multiclass classfication. I also check GBT in scikit-learn library for machine learning. The implementation of GBT is GradientBoostingClassifier which used regression tree as the weak learners for multiclass classification.

> *GB builds an additive model in a forward stage-wise fashion; it allows for the optimization of arbitrary differentiable loss functions. In each stage n_classes_ regression trees are fit on the negative gradient of the binomial or multinomial deviance loss function. Binary classification is a special case where only a single regression tree is induced.*

Source : http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier

The things is, why do we use regression tree as our learners for GBT instead of classification tree ? It would be very helpful, if someone can provide me the explanation about why regression tree is being used rather than classification tree and how regression tree can do the classification. Thank you

Comment: If the answer was helpful, kindly accept it (or provide feedback why it was not); answers take up valuable time for respondents - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are interpreting 'regression' too literally here (as numeric prediction), which is not the case; remember, classification is handled with logistic *regression*. See, for example, the entry for loss in the documentation page you have linked:

> **loss** : {‘deviance’, ‘exponential’}, optional (default=’deviance’)
>
> loss function to be optimized. ‘deviance’ refers to deviance (= logistic regression) for classification with probabilistic outputs. For loss ‘exponential’ gradient boosting recovers the AdaBoost algorithm.

So, a 'classification tree' is just a regression tree with `loss='deviance'`...